# How to make improve this simple counter on php

Tags: php, counter

I make this simple counter

```
$now = date ("d");
$filename = $now .".txt";

$lastcount="";

if (file_exists($filename))
{
    if (time()-filemtime($filename) > 2 * 86400) {
    } else {
        $lastcount=strval(intval (file_get_contents($filename))+1);
    }
}

file_put_contents($filename, $lastcount);
```

Basically it reads a file, then add 1, then rewrite

The problem is between the time I read the file, and writing it back, another copy of the program may read the file and write it.

So how do I make that atomic?

I also want to ensure that the whole script won't "crash" because of this locking.

So how to improve this counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock file using [flock](http://php.net/flock). Use exclusive locking to write to file safely:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "rw");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    // write here
    // ...

    // release the file
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    // can't use it yet. Wait a little.
}
```